# Am I not allowed to return response in exchangeToMono with Mono.just?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient

I want to return a header and body as a form of data responded from WebClient.
here is a code that I have tried

```java
var res = webclient.post()
                .uri(URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(token);
                })
                .bodyValue(body)
                .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    if (response.statusCode().value() >= 204) {
                        return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                .flatMap(message -> Mono.error(new MyException(message, response.statusCode())));
                    }

                    return Mono.just(response);
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(
                        new SimulatorException(
                                String.format("Null has returned", country),
                                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
                        )
                ))
                .block();

res.headers().asHttpHeaders().toSingleValueMap() // No problem
res.bodyToMono(ResBodyClass.class).single().block() // NullPointerException
```

So I thought empty body might has returned, but

```java
var resBody = webclient.post()
                .uri(URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(token);
                })
                .bodyValue(body)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .single().block();

System.out.println(resBody);    // It is not null...
```

it worked fine it this way.
It is really hard to understand why response has no body at all while in `exchangeToMono`
What am I missing right now?

Comment: can you please try to extract the body inside the exchangeToMono function instead

Comment: return Mono.just(response); this itself will throw compilation error.